# Feature branch and mandatory of merges from trunk to branch

Tags: svn

I have feature branch with name **fb-login** which was created from trunk in revision 1019. In this branch I have more than 10 commits.

But I did few commits to the trunk after fb-login feature branch was created.

In [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.feature) is this part, which describes how to synchronize feature branch with trunk.

> This situation is best avoided by regularly merging trunk changes to
>   the branch. Make up a policy: once a week, merge the last week's worth
>   of trunk changes to the branch.

Or

> Another way of thinking about this pattern is that your weekly sync of
>   trunk to branch is analogous to running svn update in a working copy,
>   while the final merge step is analogous to running svn commit from a
>   working copy.

My question is whether this merges from trunk to feature branch are required.

Now I want to merge my feature branch back to trunk and I need to know, if I need to do before the merge from my trunk to this feature branch.

Comment: Perhaps you can also find the following helpful You can use this utility in order to automate svn merging from one branch to another http://github.com/liveperson/Auto-Merger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this merge from trunk to branch is not required. It just makes it easier to merge back to trunk later because there will be fewer conflicts if you've been merging as you go.

In older SVN clients (i.e. before version 1.8) there was a "reintegrate merge" which sometimes made it easy to overwrite changes on trunk instead of triggering conflicts that had to be merged manually, if you hadn't merged changes from trunk. But now if I understand correctly you always just specify the same kind of merge and SVN just "does the right thing" automatically.